# Can't use variable as a URL in Network Image but using the URL directly inside the parameter works fine. Shows Error: No host specified in URI

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-image

Here the Network image won't load up when i pass the imageURL variable inside it. But if i use the URL directly inside the parameter then it works fine. How do i resolve this issue since I need to take the URL from FirebaseFirestore so i must store it inside a String variable.

Doing this works fine - `NetworkImage('https://images.ctfassets.net/3s5io6mnxfqz/6ZImCEzx6UuvuKaAiZEDDN/50479ee4a0902deb4eb1bab720ce248a/image1.jpg');`

But this doesn't work -
`NetworkImage(imageURL);`

```
class _MainOrderScreenState extends State<MainOrderScreen> {
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  
  String imageURL =
      'https://images.ctfassets.net/3s5io6mnxfqz/6ZImCEzx6UuvuKaAiZEDDN/50479ee4a0902deb4eb1bab720ce248a/image1.jpg';

 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 20),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text(
              'currently serving:',
              style: kTiffinzoTitle.copyWith(fontSize: 40),
            ),
            Image(
              image: imageURL != null
                  ? NetworkImage(imageURL)
                  : null,
              width: 200,
            ),
            Container(
              decoration: kButtonStyle,
              child: FlatButton(
                child: Text('Log out'),
                onPressed: () {
                  _auth.signOut();
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to comment out a few lines but other than that I reproduced your exact code in DartPad. The code works as expected. The image also loaded as expected. Please see the code below :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MainOrderScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class MainOrderScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  MainOrderScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainOrderScreenState createState() => _MainOrderScreenState();
}

class _MainOrderScreenState extends State<MainOrderScreen> {
  //final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  //FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  String imageURL =   'https://images.ctfassets.net/3s5io6mnxfqz/6ZImCEzx6UuvuKaAiZEDDN/50479ee4a0902deb4eb1bab720ce248a/image1.jpg';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 20),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text(
                'currently serving:',
                //style: kTiffinzoTitle.copyWith(fontSize: 40),
              ),
              Image(
                image: imageURL != null ? NetworkImage(imageURL) : null,
                width: 200,
              ),
              Container(
                //decoration: kButtonStyle,
                child: FlatButton(
                  child: Text('Log out'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    //_auth.signOut();
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```